# How to pass parameter from Selenium Webdriver to JMeter?

Tags: selenium, web-applications, automation, jmeter, load-testing

I need your guidance for passing username and password from **Selenium Script** to **JMeter**. Here's the scenario..

There is a CSV file which contains list of user names and passwords. In Selenium Webdriver, I have written a script for logging to my web application.

The script should take the user name and password from **JMeter** wherein **CSV Config File** is used as an external data source (where the list of usernames and passwords present).

How do we do this?

Thanks, 
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 5):

Given that you have defined variables as `${username}` and `${password}` you have 2 options:

Option 1: provide aforementioned variables via "Parameters" section and access them via `WDS.args[0]` and `WDS.args[1]` like in the below screenshot

[image: WDS args]

Alternatively you can get username and password from JMeter Variables as:

```
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()

var username = vars.get('username')
var password = vars.get('password')
```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks.

Comment: Where should I store the credentials to get like this in my Web Driver Sampler ??

Comment: Wherever you want, for example if you have only one username/password combination - go for [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables), if there are many of them - put them into a .CSV file and read them via [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Comment: Thanks for your immense help !! Yes, I have figured it out somehow and also use the different credentials using CSV file and configure it with CSV Data set config and use those variables with the help of your above working example and it runs successfully in my case !! Now I will definitely try your another way how can I use the `User Defined Variables`. Can we use 100 or more usernames and passwords in the `User Defined Variables` ??